# issue while deploying gcp cloud function deployment

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I have following issue while deploying the cloud function (I am completely new to gcp and terraform )

I am trying to deploy a cloud function through the terraform; but the issue is that when I am deploying its destroying an existing cloud function which was already deployed in gcp (deployed by other colleague) even though cloud function name , bucket object name and archive file name are different (only bucket name and project id  are same)

looks like its taking the state of existing cloud function which is already deployed

is there any way to keep the existing state unaffected?

code Snippet(as mentioned above there is already one cloud function deployed with same project id and bucket)

```
main.tf:
provider "google" {
  project = "peoject_id"
  credentials = "cdenetialfile"
  region  = "some-region"
}

locals {
  timestamp = formatdate("YYMMDDhhmmss", timestamp())
    root_dir = abspath("./app/")
}

data "archive_file" "archive" {
  type        = "zip"
  output_path = "/tmp/function-${local.timestamp}.zip"
  source_dir = local.root_dir
}

resource "google_storage_bucket_object" "object_archive" {
  name   = "archive-${local.timestamp}.zip"
  bucket = "dev-bucket-tfstate"
  source = "/tmp/function-${local.timestamp}.zip"
  depends_on = [data.archive_file.archive]
  
}


resource "google_cloudfunctions_function" "translator_function" {
  name = "Cloud_functionname"
  available_memory_mb = 256
  timeout = 61
  runtime = "java11"
  source_archive_bucket = "dev-bucket-tfstate"
  source_archive_object = google_storage_bucket_object.object_archive.name
  entry_point = "com.test.controller.myController"
  event_trigger {
    event_type = "google.pubsub.topic.publish"
    resource = "topic_name"
  }
}
```

---

backend.tf

```
terraform {
  backend "gcs" {
    bucket = "dev-bucket-tfstate"
    credentials = "cdenetialfile"
  }
}
```

Comment: Please execute `terraform plan` (not terraform apply) and take a look at the output. Looks like you have copied the terraform state and applying the new state removes the old one.

Comment: thanks for the response 

I checked the terraform plan out put its says

google_storage_bucket_object.archive: Refreshing state... [id=cl-temp-tfstate-archive_triggrer-210713050746.zip]
google_cloudfunctions_function.function: Refreshing state.

And also 
old function will be destroyed and (syntax: old function name: will be destroyed )
new function will be created(syntax :new_function name will be created)
How to deploy new cloud function without affecting the existing function?

Comment: is there any way to keep the existing state unaffected?

Comment: I don't use terraform with cloud function for this reason. I had the same issue and I didn't find a solution. And I'm curious about the SO community answer on that.

Comment: @JohnHanley edited as suggested

Comment: added code snippet

Comment: I am bale to deploy code after long analysis....just need to store the state of each function in different folder within bucket(just added prefix="sub-folder-name" to my backend.tf to create subfolder within bucket)